# Generate JSON result from MySQL database with total number of records per day for a Task record?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json

I am wanting to use this JavaScript library https://kamisama.github.io/cal-heatmap/ to generate an Event style heatmap like GitHub uses.

I plan to use it to represent how many actions occur on my Project Management application per day on a Task record.

For example each square will be 1 day.  It's color and number of items shown when you hover a square will be the total number of activities performed on that Task record for that day.

A Task activity includes:

- task title, description, due date, milestone, priority, assigned user, or tags being updated.
- Comment or comment reply being posted on the task record.

So on 6/17/2015 if 5 comments are made on a Task and the assigned user field is updated.  It would show 6 items for that days square on the generated heatmap.

[image]

What I need help with is generating the JSON  that will generate the Heatmap for each Task record.

I will be pulling the **Task Activities** for a Task from a MySQL Database.

So I should be able to query the database to count all records created in my activity DB table per day on a Task.

My Heatmap start and end dates will be the start date set as the date the Task record was created.  The End date will be today's date.

Assuming my MySQL Database structure looks like this:

```
Table name: task_activities
activity_id 
task_id
activity_type
created_datetime
```

So I will need to **count** the total number of records per day whre the `task_id` = the Task record I am building the JSON output for.

The JSON output needs to be in this format:

```
{
    "timestamp": 5,
    "timestamp2": 2,
    "timestamp3": 4,
    ...
}
```

The `timestamp` needs to represent the day and the value will be the total number of MySQL Activity records on that day for that Task ID.

Can someone help me to generate the desired MySQL to generate a JSON result in that format where each day is a `Timestamp` value and the number is the total number of activities for that task record on that given day?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried, and what problems you have run into?

Comment: Something along the lines of `SELECT DATE(created_datetime) AS act_date, COUNT(activity_id) AS act_count FROM task_activities WHERE task_id=123 GROUP BY DATE(created_datetime);` to get the records, then you can loop on that to generate the array, then just `json_encode($array);`.

Comment: @bishop thanks I will set up an SQLFiddle and play with that

Comment: @bishop thanks to your help I have this working here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17f2b/5 the Database is slightly different from what I posted here as I made this up on the fly when typing this question but using the same Query structure on this other table it generated the count of records for a Task ID per Day.  All I need to figure ut is how to make the JSON have a Timestamp value for the day but I assume I would just run this query in something like PHP and then convert the DateTIme into a Timestamp so I should be good to go.  If you would like to post as an answer I will accept it

Comment: Glad it helped! I've posted an answer which includes timestamp formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to bring the data together by date, irrespective of the time of day, but the date element in each row includes a time.  Thus, you need to extract the date portion of the `date_created` field:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(DATE(`date_created`), '%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00') AS `date`, 
       COUNT(`event_id`) AS `count` 
  FROM `task_activities` 
 WHERE `task_id`='242' 
 GROUP BY DATE(`date_created`);
```

The `GROUP BY DATE()` fragment uses just the date part as the grouping element.  The `DATE_FORMAT()` fragment returns the date formatted in a custom way.  Refer to the [MySQL date & time documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) for the modifiers available.

Here is an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/17f2b/7) demoing the behavior.